# Download PDF file without opening in new tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, blob

I am using below code to download pdf file using javascript, which working perfectly fine on desktop. But on mobile file is not getting open.

```js
function downloadFile(url, fileName) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", url, true);
  req.responseType = "blob";
  req.onload = function() {
    var blob = new Blob([req.response], {
      type: "application/pdf"
    });
    //Check the Browser type and download the File.
    var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
    if (isIE) {
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
      var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.setAttribute("download", fileName);
      a.setAttribute("href", link);
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
  };
  req.send();
}
```

Comment: there is any error on console

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, for security and experience reasons, mobile browsers often block automatic downloads. I would like to give you two options, depending on your needs:

**Option 1.** You might want to modify the user approach and trigger the download by an action (such as clicking a button)

```
    function setupDownloadButton(url, fileName) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerText = "Download PDF";
        button.onclick = function() {
        downloadFile(url, fileName);
    };
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }
```

This will call the `setupDownloadButton(yourURL, yourFileName)` which ensures that the download process is based on the user action.

**Option 2.** Even though you apply Option 1, the automatic download may fail for some devices. For that case, you may consider handling the download for mobile (you could display a direct link to PDF for mobile users, allowing them to open and save it manually if automatic download fails) and downloading for desktop separately.

```
function downloadFile(url, fileName) {
    // Mobile detection
    var isMobile =/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.responseType = "blob";

    req.onload = function() {
        var blob = new Blob([req.response], { type: "application/pdf" });
        if (isMobile) {
            // For mobile devices, open the PDF in a new tab
            window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob), '_blank');
        } else {
            // For desktop browsers, proceed with the download
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = fileName;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    };
    req.send();
    }
```

I hope this will solve your problem.